# xsl matching element text in freeform xml

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have this free-form xml (no dtd, just `mystuff` for a dummy namespace).
Problem is that my select statement isn't finding the element. Is this an xpath problem? Namespace?

```
<document xmlns="http://mystuff.org">
  <Chapter>
    <arg name="title">title is here</arg>
  </Chapter>
</document>
```

With this xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://mystuff.org">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <newdoc>
    <heading>
      <xsl:text>hey</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select='/document/Chapter/arg' />
      <xsl:text>hey</xsl:text>
    </heading>
  </newdoc>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the result, using `xsltproc`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<newdoc xmlns="http://mystuff.org">
  <heading>heyhey</heading>
</newdoc>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you omit the dummy namespace declarations, it should produce the (assumedly) expected output:

```
<newdoc>
    <heading>heytitle is herehey</heading>
</newdoc>
```

If you want to keep the dummy namespace declaration, you could put `*:` before all xpath expressions to match the empty namespace:

```
<xsl:template match="*:document">
    <newdoc>
        <heading>
            <xsl:text>hey</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="/*:document/*:Chapter/*:arg"/>
            <xsl:text>hey</xsl:text>
        </heading>
    </newdoc>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, if you can also use XSLT 2.0, you could use `xpath-default-namespace="http://mystuff.org"` in `xsl:stylesheet`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm used to processing DocBook and thought I had to have a namespace. Just making things harder for myself. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Set

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:p="http://mystuff.org">
```

and use namespace prefix

```
      <xsl:value-of select='/p:document/p:Chapter/p:arg' />
```

It results in

```
<heading>heytitle is herehey</heading>
```

Comment: Elegant, I should have thought of that!